# How to show selected legend but show all the colors in stacked geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar

I'm creating a stacked bar plot of relative abundance data, but I only want to display selected few interesting taxa in the legend. I have tried using `scale_fill_manual(values = sample(col_vector), breaks = legend_list)`. The result only shows selected legend in my `legend_list` as I wish, but all other factors shows no color. How do I show all the colors as stacked bar plot, but only show legend for factors in `legend_list`?

My code:

```
ggplot(df, aes_string(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
        scale_fill_manual(values = sample(col_vector), 
                          breaks = legend_list) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: What colors do you want the other taxa to have? Your interesting taxa are going to be very difficult to spot amongst all the other colors.

Comment: So I created a ```col_vector``` that is longer than the number of taxa I had, so I can sample this color vector to show color for each taxa. Yes, it will be hard to spot, but I do want all other taxa to have their own color, but only selected taxa in my ```legend_list``` will get to show their legend. Here is a link to this [image without legend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1apwUQ06-foDB3mhmTaiBM2mgF_NRavtL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: From a data visualisation perspective, it is honestly completely pointless to have any kind of color legend on that plot. There are just too many colors to make it interpretable. A plot should exist to demonstrate a feature of your data. At the moment, all it shows is the complexity of your data. This is occasionally a useful point to make, but if you want a few taxa to be highlighted in relation to the others, then drowning them in a sea of colors isn't going to achieve that, whatever your legend shows.

Comment: I understand your point, but that's not what I am asking. I am just curious from a technical stand point, what am I missing here? Why doesn't it show all the other colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is most likely that you are using an unnamed vector of colors. Under the hood, when you pass a vector to the `breaks` argument this vector is used as names for the color vector passed to the `values` argument. However, when the number of breaks is smaller than the number of colors only some colors get named while the names for all other colors are set to `NA`. As a consequence only the categories specified via the `breaks` argument are assigned a fill color while all other categories are assigned the `na.value` which by default is `"grey50"`.

As your provided no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I use a basic example based on the `ggplot2::mpg` dataset to first try to reproduce you issue before offering a fix:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

base <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_bar() 

legend_list <- c("audi", "volkswagen")

col_vector <- scales::hue_pal()(n_distinct(mpg$manufacturer))

base + scale_fill_manual(values = sample(col_vector), breaks = legend_list)
```

[image]

One option to fix the issue is to use a named vector of colors. Doing so all categories are assigned a color but only the categories specified via the `breaks` argument will show up in the legend:

```r
names(col_vector) <- sample(unique(mpg$manufacturer))

base + scale_fill_manual(values = col_vector, breaks = legend_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I named the ```col_vector``` like you suggested, and it worked just as I imagined! And thanks for providing information about reproducible example! Will follow that next time.